# PostgreSQL: restrict a GUC variable to only be set in proconfig?

Tags: postgresql

If a C extension defines a custom GUC variable, is there any combination of GUC "context","source","flags", etc., that can be used to make the system only allow it to be set from the `SET` (i.e. `proconfig`) attribute of a function declaration, and not from an ordinary `SET` command?

Or, is there any way for a check or assign hook for that variable to tell whether the assignment is coming from a `proconfig` and otherwise reject it?

Comment: Aside from my answer ... *why*? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: So far just daydreaming about a sort of fine-grained version of `SECURITY DEFINER`, where perhaps an event trigger on function creation would stop you from declaring any function with `SET missile TO armed` unless your role can do that, but now the function can't do just _anything_ your role can do, only arm missiles.

Comment: Hmm ... I was thinking how much less I would like that if the `fmgr_hook` approach forced them to be set elsewhere so the familiar syntax couldn't be used ... but maybe an event trigger could take care of that detail too.

Comment: Are you aware of row-level security? If you're looking for fine-grained mandatory security policy, you very likely want row-level security and/or sepostgresql.

Comment: Sure, I might want those too.  "Defense in depth," I think, is the phrase. :)

Comment: I think your only other sane option is to add a new PGC_ flag and pass that as the set context instead of `PGC_S_SESSION`. Then you could test that in your hooks. That'll require you to run a patched PostgreSQL, and possibly change existing callsites for GUC set hooks where those hooks don't have a fallthrough case that does what you want. You *could* poke at global state, inspect the stack, etc from your GUC set hook, but that's way past brown paper bag territory.

Answer (score 1):

There's no flag for it, though it's an interesting idea.

If `proconfig` is non-null then the security-definer function call path `fmgr_security_definer` is invoked. Interestingly this means that using function-level `SET` has a higher overhead, which I didn't expect. That path can be entered if a fmgr hook is needed or if the function is actually `SECURITY DEFINER` so you can't use that alone for testing how a var is set.

Applying proconfig creates a new GUC nesting level with `NewGUCNestLevel` then applies the GUC array with `ProcessGUCArray`, passing flags `PGC_USERSET` (for non-superusers) and `PGC_S_SESSION`. Those are the same flags passed to a normal `SET` so it doesn't look like there's any information cleanly available to GUC callbacks to tell if they're called in this context.

However:

It looks like you can hook function entry/exit in the fmgr. See `FmgrHookIsNeeded`, `needs_fmgr_hook` and `fmgr_hook`. A demonstration of use of the fmgr hook infrastructure can be found in `contrib/sepgsql`. This would let you apply custom GUCs that're otherwise defined as not settable at session level. You couldn't put them in `proconfig` though, since the fmgr will try to apply them and fail; you'd have to store them elsewhere. You can't apply them and remove them from the proconfig array because it's cached and you *really* don't want to go modifying things returned from the syscache. Anyway, the fmgr hook is fired just after GUCs are applied.

I'd look into doing it with a fmgr hook.